# IMG link overlay on hover

Tags: html, css, image

I am wondering how to set green overlay on img with link.

```
<section>
  <div class='container>
    <div class='row'>
      <a href ='https://stackoverflow.com/' target="_blank">
        <img src="i cant cause i need at least 10 rep to post images">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Only css or bootstrap4, no frameworks.
Can anyone help? :)

Comment: What is a "green overlay"?

Comment: I want green overlay on hover on img, not opacity but green color on whole img

Comment: You're going to have to at least *try* to explain what that means without repeating the words "green overlay".

Comment: https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/show-color-overlay-image-hover-using-css/ like here but without any span/div? this solution doesnt work for me btw ;o

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/96rdq198/4/)?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pure css for this. This would make your image background green on hover.

```
img{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-image: url("URL TO IMAGE");
}

img:hover{
   background-color: green;
   background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Comment: nah, i need my image under the green color with opacity

Comment: I updated my answer to fit that requirement. Just change the color as needed.

Comment: oh thanks, with background its working, but im wondering how to do it without background-image etc.

Comment: I changed it to use CSS blend mode instead of the inset box shadow.

Comment: For that you would need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Or you could use a regular image and use the inset box-shadow.